# If I'm using Google Analytics in my iOS app, do I have to answer yes to containing cryptography?

Tags: ios, cryptography, google-analytics

I've implemented the new Google Analytics SDK into my iOS app. Does this mean I have to answer yes to the cryptography question when submitting to the App Store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You probably should. Since Google Analytics uses cryptography, you better tick yes. If you don't, then when Apple gets around to testing your app and finds out it does, they might reject it and you will have to go through the process over again.

Comment: Although Nickolay may be right, I would rather be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that they use something other than SSL connection to their site, which logically should be done by basic system libraries.
So I would recommend to answer 'NO' on cryptography usage.